# Auto-complete JavaScript braces in VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I don't like most auto-completion of parentheses/quotes in VS Code, but I would like to have braces auto completed. That is, if I type:

```
function foo(thing) {
```

I would like to get the following (where | is the cursor):

```
function foo(thing) {
   |
}
```

And similarly for `if` etc.

Is there a way to achieve this in VS Code?

Comment: BYOP  - Build Your Own Plugin

Comment: Hoping for an existing solution.

Comment: write a few snippets for `function` and `if`

Answer (score 1):

It's a build in feature.

1. Click Manage icon on the bottom left corner -> Settings

[image]

2. Clear Search Settings
3. Click User Tab-> Text Editor->

**Auto Closing Bracklets -> Always**

**Auto Closing Quotes -> Never**

[image]

Comment: That has two problems compared to what I specified in the question. It also applies for parentheses (which I don't want), and it doesn't add the line breaks (which I do want).